# call compile-time-checked method with dynamic arguments in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, static, method-call

Ok, this is what I want to do:

```
public static void CallStaticMethod(Type myType, String methodName, Object[] parameters)
{
     MethodInfo m = myType.GetMethod(methodName); // make this compile-time safe
     m.Invoke(null, parameters);                  // methodName method is supposed to be static
}
```

Now, myType.GetMethod(methodName) can fail at runtime if "methodName" does not exist.
Is there any way to make this compile-time safe?
(supposing the parameters are correct)

I'd like to call the method somehow like this:

```
CallStaticMethod(()=>MyType.MyMethod(), Object[] parameters)
```

notice that this doesn't work since you need to specify the arguments inside the lambda expression.

*In other words, I need a compile-time safe handle on a method.
I can get one on a type using typeof(), but is it possible for a method?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function pointers, that is, delegates.
Simple example:

```
delegate int StringIntParse(string value);

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringIntParse p = int.Parse;
        Console.WriteLine(p("34"));
        Console.WriteLine(p.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { "43" }));
        return 0;
    }
```

You can use DynamicInvoke on any delegate, e.g.:

```
static object InvokeAnyDelegate(Delegate d, params object[] args)
{
    return d.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```